# Haskell how to use map to return a list?

Tags: list, haskell

I am a bit confused on how to return a list of something in a data type. I figure I have to use the map function, but am unsure how to use it in this context. For example, if I have the data type below (weird I know, but this specifically), how would I write a function

```
makeList :: Car -> [Make]
makeList map f ???
```

that returns a list of makes of all the cars in the input (like below), and an empty list [ ] if "makeList Tail" is given.

```
data Car = Model Make Car | Tail

> makeList (Car Audi (Car Porsche Tail))
  [Audi,Porsche]
> makeList Tail
  [ ]
```

Comment: This is at least the second question I've seen recently that had the [tag:dictionary] tag but had nothing to do with dictionaries. I'm curious if you have any insight as to why that might be happening.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to remove essential information like the definition of `Car`. I have reverted your edit.

Answer (score 5):

The `Car` type is equivalent (mathematicians would use the term *isomorphic*) to lists in Haskell specialized to the `Make` data type.  Haskell lists are defined as

```
data [a] = a : [a] | []
```

Where `:` and `[]` are the constructors.  If we give them more human readable names it might make more sense

```
data List a = Cons a (List a) | Empty
```

All I've done is substitute `[a]` for `List a`, `:` for `Cons`, and `[]` for `Empty`.  If we specialize this to a specific type, such as `Int`, we would have

```
data List = Cons Int List | Empty
```

Now we see to correlation between Haskell lists and your `Car` type, it's just that `Car = List`, `Model = Cons`, and `Tail = Empty`.

Your `makeList` function is actually just converting a `Car` style list into a `[]` style list, `map` isn't necessary (and wouldn't be useful, since it only works on `[]` style lists).  Instead, you'll just need to do the right substitutions

```
makeList :: Car -> [Make]
makeList Tail = []
makeList (Car make nextCar) = ...
```

I don't want to give everything away since this sounds like homework, but at this point you simply need to make the second clause of `makeList` recursively construct a normal `[]` style list.  Again, the big hints are "recursively" and "`[]` style list".